# Оптимизация MySQL-запросов для поля created_at

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, оптимизация

Имеется таблица с более, чем 3 млн строк. По этой таблице необходимо делать запрос на получение количества строк в определённые временные промежутки (для этого имеется поле `created_at` : `Date`). Думал над созданием индекса по полю `created_at`, однако поскольку данных довольно много, индекс займёт очень много места. Тем более, что у поля created_at сильно точные значения, поэтому думаю, что индекс будет и не совсем эффективен. Подскажите, что можно придумать

Comment: Какие обычно запрашиваются промежутки времени по сравнению с полным диапазоном дат? Какая доля записей в такие промежутки попадает? Если небольшая, то индекс видится вполне подходящим решением

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin используются только запросы вида `created_at  > 01.01.2019 and created_at < 02.01.2019`

Comment: Если предположить, что данные в основном вставляются и не удаляются, запросы на статистику не очень частые, извлекают проценты строк, индекс скорее всего подойдёт. Если совсем жалко места, и точность данных не критична, можно сделать таблицу со статистикой по суткам и обновлять периодически. Тогда запросы на исторические данные к ней отправлять.

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin очень крутая идея, спасибо! Если оформите ваш комментарий как ответ, то отмечу его, как правильный

Comment: Эта идея называется ROLAP, если все же производительность запросов с использованием индекса не удовлетворяет по тек вашим потребностям, то можете отдельно изучить этот вопрос, как проектировать, как наполнять через ETL. Хотя честно говоря было бы странно если индекс не удовлетворит ваши требования по производительности, так как с ним выборки нормально работали и из таблиц в несколько СОТЕН миллионов. Хотя ROLAP и как развитие MOLAP будут работать существенно быстрее и давать большую гибкость. Для начала можно кстати сделать эмитацию ROLAP на вьюхах. Мы такой финт используем, чтобы пока без ETL